# How to test Fastapi Exception Handler

Tags: python, exception, pytest, fastapi

I created a custom exception handler and wanted to write test cases for it.

This is my Testcase:

```py
def test_is_exception_raised(app_client):
    exception = CustomException(InvalidSQLStatement())
    with pytest.raises(exception):
        raise exception

    try:
        raise exception
    except Exception as e:
        assert e.message
        assert e.status_code
```

This is the error I get:

[image: error message]

My Code looks like this:
`main.py`

```py
@app.exception_handler(CustomException)
async def custom_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: CustomException):
    log.error(f"{exc}")
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=exc.status_code_number,
        content=jsonable_encoder({exc.status_code_number: exc.message}),
    )
```

`exceptions.py`

```py
class CustomException(Exception):
    """
    All Custom Exceptions are defined in xyz\exceptions.py
    """

    def __init__(self, exception):
        if not check_if_exception_exists(exception):
            raise KeyError(f"Custom Exception: {exception.__class__.__name__} does not exist.")
        self.message = exception.message
        self.status_code_number = exception.status_code_number
```

Comment: `with pytest.raises(CustomException):`? Since you're testing that the exception type gets raised, not that a specific instance is raised? Also be aware that if you're using `TestClient`, no exceptions are returned - since the exception handler inside FastAPI handles them and returns a regular response; in that case you'll want to test that the `status_code` is as expected instead.

Comment: Thank you @MatsLindh    
But my CustomException expects an exception (```python def __init__(self, exception):```).  
This parameter contains all information for the test (status_code, message, etc.)

Comment: Yes, you still _raise_ that exception. But you _expect_ a `CustomException` to be raised, regardless of how it was created. `pytest.raises` expects a class, not an instance as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `raises` in the class, like this:

```
with pytest.raises(CustomException):
```

Also, you declare `status_code_number` (in exceptions.py), but use `status_code` in test case.