# FastAPI: how to test exception handler logic

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi, exceptionhandler

I am implementing exception handler logic to intercept `RetryError`s occurring at service level.

For context, in that specific case, the second argument of the handler's signature: `async def my_handler(request: Request, call_next)` is, in fact, not a callable, but the actual `RetryError`.

My manual test with the application runtime seems to indicate my fix resolves the issue.

However, I am having considerable trouble adding non-E2E coverage for the change in the handler.

**TL;DR**
My exact problem is that I cannot seem to make my test execute the handler function in test, whereas it does work at runtime.

Here's my test code:

```
@fixture(scope="session", name="exception_handler_test_client")
def get_test_client() -> TestClient:
    app = FastAPI()
    router = APIRouter()
    # see below for the "service" function that raises RetryError
    router.add_api_route("/test_exception_handler/", retryable_failure, methods=["GET"])
    app.include_router(router)
    # the real test would replace foo with the real exception handler I want to test
    app.add_exception_handler(Exception, foo)
    test_client = TestClient(router)

    return test_client

async def foo(request: Request, call_next):
    # here for convenience, the real one is somewhere else in the code base
    # and neither the real one nor this one execute on exception raised
    pass

# this does raise RetryError as expected
@retry(wait_fixed=100, stop_max_delay=1000, stop_max_attempt_number=2, retry_on_result=lambda Any: True)
def retryable_failure():
    """
    Programmatically fails a retryable function for testing purposes.
    """
    pass


# the actual test
@pytest.mark.asyncio
def test_retry_error_handled_without_hard_failure(exception_handler_test_client: TestClient) -> None:
    # TODO once the handler works I would assert on the JSON response and HTTP status
    exception_handler_test_client.get("/test_exception_handler/")
```

The test fails because it raises `RetryError` as expected, but the handler is never executed.

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73371263/how-to-test-fastapi-exception-handler) post, describing a similar issue.

The only answer mentions using `pytest.raises`, but that doesn't solve my problem at all - it just passes the test without executing the handler.

**Extra note**:

The exception handler associated with the app in test doesn't execute even if the programmatically failed retryable function is replaced with a garden-variety, non-retryable function just raising Exception.

Comment: can you try with `yield test_client` instead of `return test_client` in the `get_test_client()` fixture?

Comment: @ChristosPalyvos thanks for having a look, but I don't see how your suggestion would change anything given the context. I also tested it for good measure and it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `get_test_client()` fixture, you are building your `test_client` from the API router instance instead of the FastAPI app instance. The `TestClient` constructor [expects a FastAPI app](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/testing/#using-testclient) to initialize itself. This would also explain why the exception handler is not getting executed, since you are adding the exception handler to the `app` and not the `router` object.

I suggest replacing the line to create your test client with this:

```py
test_client = TestClient(app)
```

As a side note and like [@Christos Palyvos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76900080/fastapi-how-to-test-exception-handler-logic#comment135568730_76900080) suggested, Pytest encourages [using `yield` over `return` in fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#yield-fixtures-recommended).

Comment: Well spotted, I should have seen this thanks.